# Sending commands from phone to Arduino via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I've been trying to control a 2WD robot/car kit with my Android phone via Bluetooth using an HC-05 Bluetooth module. Everything works up until I've paired my phone. I can send commands to the BT module but the motors I'm trying to control won't move. I'm using the following code:

```
//This program is used to control a robot using a app that communicates with Arduino through a bluetooth module.
//Error Code Chart: Code 01; Turnradius is higher than Speed; Code 02; Speed is higher than 255;
#include <HC05.h>
#define in1 5 //L298n Motor Driver pins.
#define in2 6
#define in3 10
#define in4 11
#define LED 13

int command; //Int to store app command state.
int Speed = 230; // 0 - 255.
int Speedsec;
int buttonState = 0;
int lastButtonState = 0;
int Turnradius = 0; //Set the radius of a turn, 0 - 255 Note: the robot will malfunction if this is higher than int Speed.
int brakeTime = 45;
int brkonoff = 1; //1 for the electronic braking system, 0 for normal.

void setup() {
  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT); //Set the LED pin.
  Serial.begin(38400);  //Set the baud rate to your Bluetooth module.
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    command = Serial.read();
    Stop(); //Initialize with motors stopped.
    switch (command) {
      case 'F':
        forward();
        break;
      case 'B':
        back();
        break;
      case 'L':
        left();
        break;
      case 'R':
        right();
        break;
      case 'G':
        forwardleft();
        break;
      case 'I':
        forwardright();
        break;
      case 'H':
        backleft();
        break;
      case 'J':
        backright();
        break;
      case '0':
        Speed = 100;
        break;
      case '1':
        Speed = 140;
        break;
      case '2':
        Speed = 153;
        break;
      case '3':
        Speed = 165;
        break;
      case '4':
        Speed = 178;
        break;
      case '5':
        Speed = 191;
        break;
      case '6':
        Speed = 204;
        break;
      case '7':
        Speed = 216;
        break;
      case '8':
        Speed = 229;
        break;
      case '9':
        Speed = 242;
        break;
      case 'q':
        Speed = 255;
        break;
    }
    Speedsec = Turnradius;
    if (brkonoff == 1) {
      brakeOn();
    } else {
      brakeOff();
    }
  }
}

void forward() {
  analogWrite(in1, Speed);
  analogWrite(in3, Speed);
}

void back() {
  analogWrite(in2, Speed);
  analogWrite(in4, Speed);
}

void left() {
  analogWrite(in3, Speed);
  analogWrite(in2, Speed);
}

void right() {
  analogWrite(in4, Speed);
  analogWrite(in1, Speed);
}
void forwardleft() {
  analogWrite(in1, Speedsec);
  analogWrite(in3, Speed);
}
void forwardright() {
  analogWrite(in1, Speed);
  analogWrite(in3, Speedsec);
}
void backright() {
  analogWrite(in2, Speed);
  analogWrite(in4, Speedsec);
}
void backleft() {
  analogWrite(in2, Speedsec);
  analogWrite(in4, Speed);
}

void Stop() {
  analogWrite(in1, 0);
  analogWrite(in2, 0);
  analogWrite(in3, 0);
  analogWrite(in4, 0);
}

void brakeOn() {
  //Here's the future use: an electronic braking system!
  // read the pushbutton input pin:
  buttonState = command;
  // compare the buttonState to its previous state
  if (buttonState != lastButtonState) {
    // if the state has changed, increment the counter
    if (buttonState == 'S') {
      if (lastButtonState != buttonState) {
        digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(in4, HIGH);
        delay(brakeTime);
        Stop();
      }
    }
    // save the current state as the last state,
    //for next time through the loop
    lastButtonState = buttonState;
  }
}

void brakeOff() {
}
```

I've opened my Serial Monitor and this is what happens. The Serial Monitor doesn't print in real time the commands I'm pressing on my phone. When I disconnect my phone from the bluetooth, it prints them all in one line like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6G2d.jpg). I've done it twice. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0wIP.jpg) is my wiring diagram so far if anyone wants to see.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what's wrong. Could it be that I should try other phones? Or just that the board can't keep up with the communication of the bluetooth?

**EDIT** I'd also like to point out that my Bluetooth module is blinking every 2 seconds. This might mean I'm in AT mode and I can't get to Comms mode.

Comment: any own debugging attempts?

Comment: I've tried adding delays to the void functions and set the baud rate down to 9600. Still, no luck.

Comment: The commands you send from your phone need to be terminated with a newline, most probably. Every time I have seen a problem like what you describe, the reason was that Serial was accumulating data. When disconnecting, it would flush down the accumulated on the serial monitor. And only then.

Comment: How do I go about this problem? I've tried setting the datastream from my phone to be every button press instead and it doesn't register any command aside from "S" or stop. But say, I press forward twice, it prints out "SFS". I'm guessing it stops at the "stop" function and passes it onto the board?

Comment: @dda newlines don't flush any buffer. he's the guy who sends and receives data so he only needs to send a newline if he processes it on the receiving side which is not the case here

Comment: make sure you actually receive the data, make sure that your movement functions work. how often do you send the commands? and why do you stop the motors in every loop cycle immediately after starting them?

Comment: If the serial monitor is any indication, I'm receiving those commands. I think my code would be to blame why it stops every loop cycle as the "Stop" function is set as the default state. Does the module need to be in Comms mode? The LED blinks once every two seconds and i think that means its in AT mode. I haven't done anything yet to my module, I just used it straight out of the box.